# how to save multiple data in swift ios using alert textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

How would it be possible to save multiple data from ui alert textfield , i have made it possible to save one data to the database  with this line of code. as you notice there is just one textfield i added 2 textfield for saving other data like address , date but when i save the data only name that was saved. the part of the code is Add New Chore . and the function for saving it is on    func saveItemInLocalDB(groceryItem : Item) you can find it below.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Chore", message: "", preferredStyle:
                    UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: textFieldHandler)
```

import UIKit
    import CoreData

```
class GroceryViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, GroceryItemCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var seeTask: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var see: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    let unselectedCellColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 60/255, green: 78/255, blue: 127/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let selectedCellColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 173/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0)

    var searchBarActive : Bool?
    var textToSearch : String?
    var loggedInUserHouseNumber  : String?
    var loggedInUsername : String?
    open var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<GroceryItem>!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    @IBAction func checkListButtonIsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let  cartVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroceryCheckListViewController") as! GroceryCheckListViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cartVC, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loggedInUserHouseNumber =  (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loggedInUserHouseNumber")  as! String)
        loggedInUsername = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loggedInUsername")  as! String)
//        likeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2 * 3))
        var a =  loggedInUsername
        if ((a?.lowercased().range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
            seeTask.setTitle("Completed Tasks", for: .normal)
            print("true")

        } else {
            print("false")
             seeTask.setTitle("View Details",for: .normal)
//            self.collectionView.isd = true
        }
        searchBarActive = false
        textToSearch = nil

        self.navigationItem.title = "Chore List"

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

        self.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.setUpCollectionView()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func createDatePicker() {

    }

    func setUpCollectionView() {
        configureFetchedResultsController()

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred")

        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func configureFetchedResultsController() {

        self.fetchedResultsController =  nil

        let itemsFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<GroceryItem>(entityName: "GroceryItem")
        let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        // let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "commonName", ascending: true)

        if (textToSearch != nil) {
             itemsFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@ AND houseNo == %@",textToSearch!, loggedInUserHouseNumber!)
        } else {
             itemsFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "houseNo == %@",loggedInUserHouseNumber!)
        }

        itemsFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]

        self.context = getContext()
        self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<GroceryItem>(
            fetchRequest: itemsFetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: getContext(),
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)

        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if  self.searchBarActive! {
            if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
                let currentSection = sections[section]
                return currentSection.numberOfObjects
            }
            return 0
        } else {
            if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
                let currentSection = sections[section]
                return (currentSection.numberOfObjects + 1)
            }
            return 0
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if self.searchBarActive! {

            // get a reference to our storyboard cell
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! GroceryItemCollectionViewCell
            cell.buttonDelegate = self

            let item = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

            cell.label.text = item.name
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row

            if item.isSelected {
                cell.backgroundColor = selectedCellColor
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = unselectedCellColor
            }
            return cell

        } else {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                // get a reference to our storyboard cell
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddNewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AddNewCollectionViewCell
                cell.backgroundColor = unselectedCellColor // make cell more visible in our example project
                return cell
            } else {

                let index = IndexPath(row: (indexPath.row - 1), section: 0)

                let item = fetchedResultsController.object(at: index)

                // get a reference to our storyboard cell
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! GroceryItemCollectionViewCell
                cell.buttonDelegate = self
                cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row - 1
                cell.label.text = item.name

                if item.isSelected {
                    cell.backgroundColor = selectedCellColor
                } else {
                    cell.backgroundColor = unselectedCellColor
                }
                return cell
            }
        }
    }

    func buttonTapped(cell: GroceryItemCollectionViewCell) {
        let index = IndexPath(row: (cell.deleteButton.tag), section: 0)
        self.context.delete(fetchedResultsController.object(at: index))
        self.setUpCollectionView()

    }


    func textFieldHandler(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        label.text = "Text"
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Chore Name"

        if (textField) != nil {
            print("true")

        }
    }
    func textFieldHandler1(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        label.text = "Text"
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Date"

        if (textField) != nil {
            print("true")

        }
    }

    func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func saveItemInLocalDB(groceryItem : Item) {
        let context = getContext()

        //retrieve the entity that we just created
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "GroceryItem", in: context)

        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        //set the entity values
        item.setValue(groceryItem.name, forKey: "name")
        item.setValue(false, forKey: "isSelected")
        item.setValue(loggedInUserHouseNumber, forKey: "houseNo")

        //save the object
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("ang item:", groceryItem.name)
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        if self.searchBarActive! {

            let index = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)
            let item = fetchedResultsController.object(at: index)

            if item.isSelected {
                item.isSelected =  false
                cell?.backgroundColor = unselectedCellColor

            } else {
                item.isSelected = true
                cell?.backgroundColor = selectedCellColor
            }

            do {
                try context.save()
                print("saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } catch {

            }

        } else {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Chore", message: "", preferredStyle:
                    UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: textFieldHandler)
                alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: textFieldHandler1)



//                alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
//                    textField.placeholder = "Enter Chore Name"
//                })

                let a =  loggedInUsername
                if ((a?.lowercased().range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
                print("true")
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

                    let newItem : String = (alert.textFields?.first?.text)!
                    if !newItem.isEmpty {

                        let item = Item(name: newItem)
//                        let item2 = Item(name: newItem2)
                        self.saveItemInLocalDB(groceryItem: item!)


                        self.setUpCollectionView()

                    }
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)

                } else {
                    let alertVC : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Access", message: "please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print("false")

                }
            } else {

                 let index = IndexPath(row: (indexPath.row - 1), section: 0)
                let item = fetchedResultsController.object(at: index)

                if item.isSelected {
                    item.isSelected =  false
                    cell?.backgroundColor = unselectedCellColor

                } else {
                    item.isSelected = true
                    cell?.backgroundColor = selectedCellColor
                }

                do {
                    try context.save()
                    print("saved!")
                } catch let error as NSError  {
                    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                } catch {

                }
            }
        }
    }


    // This method updates filteredData based on the text in the Search Box
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if (searchBar.text?.isEmpty)!{
            searchBarActive =  false
            textToSearch = nil
        } else {
            searchBarActive = true
            textToSearch = searchText
        }
        self.setUpCollectionView()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBarActive =  false
        textToSearch = nil
        self.searchBar.text = ""
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.setUpCollectionView()
       // self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBarActive =  true
        textToSearch = searchBar.text
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.setUpCollectionView()
       // self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        self.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        self.searchBarActive =  false
        textToSearch = nil
        self.setUpCollectionView()
       // self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    }


    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            break;
        case .update:
            break;
        case .move:
            break;
        case .delete:
            break;
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my Understanding, You are trying to add more than one data with same fields.

So I guess you can use my approach of saving data

```
func saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery:String){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let groceryData = GroceryItem(context: context) // Link GroceryItem & Context
    groceryData.name = nameOfGroccery
    groceryData.isSelected = false
    groceryData.houseNo = loggedInUserHouseNumber
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

This will save all your data at a time.

**In Reference to you question In Comments**

You can try following piece of logic

**Step:1** Create a Variable at top

```
var strName:String = String()
```

**Step:2** Modify your code like below

```
strName = (alert.textFields?.first?.text)!

                    if strName != ""{

                        self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: strName)
                    }
```

**Code to Add TextField in Alert:**

```
    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Chore", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = "Some default text"
    }

    // 3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.

        if textField?.text != ""{
            print("Text field: \(textField?.text!)")
            self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: textField?.text)
        }
    }))

    // 4. Present the alert.
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```